# Publishing failed in stage Committing Deployment SDL Tridion 2011 SP1 - HR1

Tags: 2011, content-delivery, publishing

Got this error when publishing css file:

> Phase:
>
> Deployment Prepare Commit Phase failed,
>
> Unable to prepare transaction: tcm:0-104418-66560,
>   org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not insert: [com.tridion.storage.ComponentMeta],
>   org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not insert: [com.tridion.storage.ComponentMeta],
>
> Unable to prepare transaction: tcm:0-104418-66560,
>   org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not insert: [com.tridion.storage.ComponentMeta],
>   org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not insert: [com.tridion.storage.ComponentMeta]

Some of the settings from `<Storages>` section from `cd_storage_conf.xml` file:

```xml
<Storage Type="persistence" Id="defaultdb" dialect="MSSQL"
         Class="com.tridion.storage.persistence.JPADAOFactory" defaultStorage="true">
  <Pool Type="jdbc" Size="5" MonitorInterval="60" IdleTimeout="120" CheckoutTimeout="120" />
  <DataSource Class="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDataSource">
    <Property Name="serverName" Value="******" />
    <Property Name="portNumber" Value="1759" />
    <Property Name="databaseName" Value="***" />
    <Property Name="user" Value="****" />
    <Property Name="password" Value="****" />
  </DataSource>
</Storage>

<Storage Type="filesystem" Class="com.tridion.storage.filesystem.FSDAOFactory"
         Id="*****" defaultFilesystem="false">
  <Root Path="C:\inetpub\wwwroot\*****" />
</Storage>

<ItemTypes defaultStorageId="defaultdb" cached="false">
```

Any help will be highly appreciated.

I haven't tried with any other file.

Many thanks,
Vip

Comment: Could you edit your question and provide more information, specifically the `<Storages>` section of your `cd_storage_conf.xml` and also does this issue happen for all the items you publish or just a specific one?

Comment: Thanks Bart for your quick reply. I have now reformatted my question.

Comment: Adding the `<ItemTypes>` mapping from `cd_storage_conf.xml` could also help, sorry for not asking that earlier. Also you mention you are publishing a css file, is that a Page or a Multimedia Component in SDL Tridion?

Comment: <ItemTypes defaultStorageId="defaultdb" cached="false">

Comment: and css file is actually a page. This page have five components and they are using raw data components template.

Comment: Considering your default storage is database, in combination with the listed error, there is something going wrong in there. I would really need more information from the Content Delivery logs. That is assuming that this used to work, else I would trace back your installation/configuration steps of the Content Delivery side...

Comment: I am not sure if it is something I have seen before, but can you confirm if you are using a SDL Tridion Default Finish Action TBB or a customized Default Finish Action TBB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ConstraintViolationException

This makes me think of an issue with the database version... might be something else, but that's the only case where I usually get this type of errors.

Please double check the version of the Broker database

Answer (score 6):

Try applying the cumulative hotfix CD_2011.1.1.83467 from https://www.sdltridionworld.com/ (login required).

As stated, this contains

> TT82946 Publish to the deployer fail with the exception "org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not insert"

In addition, You state...

> I haven't tried with any other file

why not try? Perhaps with a file with no Component Presentations to remove that from the equation.

Also - did you recently upgrade? Is this a clean installation?

Comment: Other files work fine.

Answer (score 5):

> ConstraintViolationException

I've also seen this when publishing binaries associated to dynamic component templates.  The issue was related the use duplicate file names.

This issue actually lead to the development of this tool: https://code.google.com/p/tridion-2011-power-tools/wiki/DuplicateBinaries to ensure that the publication didn't contain binaries with the same file names.

Could it be in your css you are referencing binaries and have some file name conflicts?

Answer (score 2):

I have seen a similar error before -- it had to do with the auto id sequence on the database tables, which was wrong.

The fix included working directly on the database tables and altering some SQL statements. Please contact SDL WCM Customer Support to get support on this, because touching the database directly can get you to an unsupported system.

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into this problem where every phase was successful except the commit phase. It was resolved when I freed space on the database. There was 0 bytes free.