# "Expected one result and more found: 2" when publishing JavaScript file

Tags: publishing, javascript

This is regarding an issue coming up in publishing a JavaScript file to live environment from SDL Tridion environment from one publication only. It is possible to publish the file from the other publications to live as well as staging environment.

There are three JavaScript files uploaded with the same name in the unpublished state. The issue is coming up while publishing one of the file to the Live environment while the file gets published successfully to the staging environment. It gives the error

> Expected one result and more found: 2

What does this error mean, and how can I solve my problem?
After unpublishing and renaming the duplicate files, the issue doesn't get resolved.

Comment: Even on renaming these files and removing the duplicate in name the issue is not resolved. Any help is much appreciated!!!

Comment: Are you the same person who asked the question? Is this meant to be an update to the question? I'd suggest editing the question would make more sense.

Comment: Hi, I am her colleague. Updated details in her absence.

Comment: I think it would be better to update the question and delete this answer.

Answer (score 4):

Your issue is likely caused by duplicate file names.  There's already a number of questions/answers on this website to help you resolve this:

[Publishing failed in stage Committing Deployment SDL Tridion 2011 SP1 - HR1](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/3277/publishing-failed-in-stage-committing-deployment-sdl-tridion-2011-sp1-hr1/)

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

To begin with, ensure the following are true:

1. All three javascript files inside the components have different file names (I am assuming you are not appending the TCMIDs to the filenames, while publishing)
2. After un-publishing all three components, there is no file with the same name present at the CD environment (check File system or Broker DB depending on your configuration) for that particular publication.
3. The publishing output package doesn’t have two or more files(JS, other) with the same name. (you can check the package directly on the deployer server OR use template builder to check the output)

Comment: Hi Saurabh,Thanks for your inputs.The approach has been tried but with no success in getting the actual file published.