# Getting a ConstraintViolationException when publishing to just one publication in Tridion 2011

Tags: publishing

I have the following error when publishing a component:

```
Phase: Deployment Prepare Commit Phase failed, Unable to prepare transaction: tcm:0-890101-66560,
         org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not insert: [com.tridion.storage.ComponentMeta],
         org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not insert: [com.tridion.storage.ComponentMeta], Unable to prepare transaction: tcm:0-890101-66560,
         org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not insert: [com.tridion.storage.ComponentMeta],
         org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not insert: [com.tridion.storage.ComponentMeta]
```

This is the same topic addressed in: **[Publishing failed in stage Committing Deployment SDL Tridion 2011 SP1 - HR1](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/3277/publishing-failed-in-stage-committing-deployment-sdl-tridion-2011-sp1-hr1)**

I've tried everything, I've already applied the accumulative hotfix CD_2011.1.1.83467, I edited the component and removed all binaries component and I still getting the same error.

The weird thing is I'm getting the error only in one publication, in the others I'm able to publish this component without any error.

Do you have any idea what else can I do ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a test by creating a new broker db and publishing the same item to it. If it's successful then it could be a metadata is corrupted in the original broker db

Comment: Hi Rober,Thanks for your answer, but no, I can't create a new broker db, but i think the same, the metadata for this item could be corrupted. I solved it creating a new component.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes this problem occurs when you get backup of CMS DB from Live environment but not of Broker or vice versa. so tcm-id gets out of sync. if you create component having tcm-id 180-12345, but that id already exists in broker and associated metadata tables, it will throw the above constraint violation.

Solution: take backup of both db or take CMS backup and republish content on empty Broker DB (preferred approach)