# Error while unpublishing

Tags: publishingfailed

I get error while unpublishing, failed with following explanation:

```
Committing Deployment Failed
Phase: Deployment Prepare Commit Phase failed, Unable to prepare transaction: tcm:0-4552883-66560, 
    org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: Could not execute JDBC batch update, 
    org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: Could not execute JDBC batch update, Unable to prepare transaction: tcm:0-4552883-66560, 
    org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: Could not execute JDBC batch update, 
    org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: Could not execute JDBC batch update
```

Strange is that I'm able to republish the same page successfully, but unpublishing is not working

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a repeat of [Publishing failed in stage Committing Deployment SDL Tridion 2011 SP1 - HR1](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/3277/publishing-failed-in-stage-committing-deployment-sdl-tridion-2011-sp1-hr1)

You could be missing this hotfix: CD_2011.1.1.83467